# Algorithm that increases randomness?

Tags: random

Suppose i provide you with **random seeds between 0 and 1** but after some observations you find out that my **seeds are not distributed properly** and most of them are less than 0.5, would you still be able to use this source by using an **algorithm that makes the seeds more distributed**?
If yes, please provide me with necessary sources.

Comment: You appear to be misunderstanding the role of seeds in PRNGs.  The seed is the input that determines the initial state.  It's not an output, so it doesn't make sense to talk about the distribution of the seed after some observations.  Also note that the overwhelming majority of PRNGs are integer based because of the inherent [imprecision of floating point arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de), so seeds are almost always integer-valued rather than numbers between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how numbers are distributed in interval [0...1]. In general, you need CDF (cumulative distribution function) to map some arbitrary [0...1] domain distribution into uniform [0...1]. But for some particular cases you could do some simple transformation. Code below (in Python) first construct simple unfair RNG which generates 60% of numbers below 0.5 and 40% above.

```
import random

def unfairRng():
    q = random.random()
    if q < 0.6: # result is skewed toward [0...0.5] interval
        return 0.5*random.random()

    return 0.5 + 0.5*random.random()

random.seed(312345)

nof_trials = 100000

h = [0, 0]
for k in range(0, nof_trials):
    q = unfairRng()
    h[0 if q < 0.5 else 1] += 1

print(h)
```

I count then numbers above and below 0.5, and output on my machine is

```
[60086, 39914]
```

which is quite close to 60/40 split I described.

Ok, let's "fix" RNG by taking numbers from unfairRNG and alternating just returning value and next time returning 1-value. Again, Python code

```
def fairRng():
    if (fairRng.even == 0):
        fairRng.even = 1
        return unfairRng()
    else:
        fairRng.even = 0
        return 1.0 - unfairRng()

fairRng.even = 0

h = [0, 0]
for k in range(0, nof_trials):
    q = fairRng()
    h[0 if q < 0.5 else 1] += 1

print(h)
```

Again, counting histogram and result is

```
[49917, 50083]
```

which "fix" unfair RNG and make it fair.

Answer (score 0):

Flipping a coin out of an unfair coin is done by flipping twice and, if the results are different, using the first; otherwise, discard the result.

This results in a coin with exactly 50/50 chance, but it's not guaranteed to run in finite time.

Comment: but seeds are not limited to just heads and tails, any number between 0 and 1 can be present

Comment: @Abhishek Look at the first digit after the decimal point. Even → "heads", Odd → "tails"

Answer (score 0):

Random number sequences generated by any algorithm will have no more entropy ("randomness") than the seeds themselves. For instance, if each seed has an entropy of only 1 bit for every 64 bits, they can each be transformed, at least in theory, to a 1 bit random number with full entropy. However, measuring the entropy of those seeds is nontrivial (*entropy estimation*). Moreover, not every algorithm is suitable in all cases for extracting the entropy of random seeds (*entropy extraction*, *randomness extraction*).